# Keeping a picturebox stuck inside another

Tags: visual-studio-2010, coordinates, mouse, positioning

I need code for Visual Basic 2010 Express.

I am doing a project in school that is about making a pupil (picturebox2) follow the mouse so that students can follow where the mouse is during a lesson. It is supposed to be "stuck" inside of something that can hold it in a rectangular "prison" but still follow the mouses movement inside of it. The "prison" is placed at the bottom left corner, and about 200x200 in size.

I could use code for getting pb2 not going outside of the prison and how I can make pb2 to follow the mouse anyway.

Sample code:

```
PictureBox2.Text = e.X.ToString
PictureBox2.Text = e.Y.ToString

Me.PictureBox2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(e.X, e.Y)
```

Comment: please give sample code or what have you tried and did not work

Comment: PictureBox2.Text = e.X.ToString
        PictureBox2.Text = e.Y.ToString
        Me.PictureBox2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(e.X, e.Y)                                                                                                                               This is the code i just to get the picturebox to follow my mouse, but I realized I needed it to be "stuck" inside Another box

Comment: And I could really use a code for how to tell pb2 that it has to stay inside of the prison.